# Issue with local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am trying to get this Local Storage script to work.

I need First Name, Last Name and State. Can I  only save one element? I have 3 lines set up, one for each element.

Also, I would like to use the jQuery append() method. So far I can only get an alert to work. alert(val); but that is not what I want and I can only get the last element to show...not first name, last name and state.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="message">

       </div>
       </p>
       <p>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      function saveLocal(){
if (window.localStorage) {
    localStorage.setItem("firstname","myfirstname");
    localStorage.setItem("lastname","mylastname");
    localStorage.setItem("lastname","state");
    alert("The data has been saved locally.");
} else {
    alert("Your Browser does not support LocalStorage.");
}
     }

   function readLocal(){
if (window.localStorage) {
    var val = localStorage.getItem("firstname");
    var val = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
    var val = localStorage.getItem("state");
    $("#message").empty().append(getVal());
}else {
    alert("Your Browser does not support LocalStorage.");
}
   }

  </script>
    </head>
  <body>
   <div id="main">
<input type="button" value="Save Values" onclick="saveLocal()"/>
<input type="button" value="Read Values" onclick="getVal()"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are storing everything into one variable named `val` and you do not have method listed called `getVal()`

```
var val = localStorage.getItem("firstname");  //<-- val
var val = localStorage.getItem("lastname");   //<-- val
var val = localStorage.getItem("state");      //<-- val
$("#message").empty().append(getVal());       //<-- What is getVal()
```

Comment: I changed to  $("#message").empty().append(val()); but that doesn't work

Comment: And are you calling the right function since your button does not call it? http://jsfiddle.net/z5DNu/

Comment: I changed to <input type="button" value="Read Values" onclick="readLocal()"/> ...and I don't want to use alert for that. I am trying to get append to work.

Comment: val() does not work since it is not a method! Learn to use your debugger! F12